# justifying convergence of complex series

Tags: complex-analysis

The question asks me to justify if the complex series converges absolutely, which leads me to think that I should use the comparison test (instead of the root or ratio tests), 
the series itself is sum from n=1 to infinity of $$1/(n^2+i)$$
But I'm not sure how to find another series to compare it to now that it is complex?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:
$$
|n^2+i|\geq|n^2|-|i|= n^2-1 .
$$

Comment: But in order to prove convergence don't I need to find something larger than the series?

Comment: If $a\ge b$ then $1/a\le 1/b$.

Comment: Actually $|n^2+i| > n^2.$